# Selection sort vs insertion sort. Huge difference in speed

Tags: r, sorting

I know, that insertion sort algorithm is faster, than selection sort.
But the difference in speed is too huge in my opinion. 
Here are my two codes:

```
#Selection sort algorithm:
u <- round(runif(100,1,100))
selection_sort <- function(x){
    s <- vector('numeric')
    while(length(x) != 0){
        minimum <- x[1]
        for(i in 1:length(x)){
            ifelse(x[i]<minimum,minimum <- x[i],next())
        }
        x <- x[-match(minimum,x)]
        s <- c(s,minimum)
    }
    s
}

#Insertion sort algorithm:
u <- round(runif(100,1,100))
insertion_sort <- function(x){
    s <- vector('numeric')
    while(length(x) !=0){
        num <- x[1]
        x <- x[-match(num,x)]
        if(length(s) == 0){
            s <- c(s,num)
        } else{
            for(i in 1:length(s)){
                if(s[i]>=num){
                    s <- append(s,num,i-1)
                    break
                }
            }
            if(s[length(s)]<num){
                s <- c(s,num)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked the speed of my codes by `microbenchmark` commend and I got the following results:

```
microbenchmark(b <- insertion_sort(u),times = 10)
expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
2.793573 2.873704 3.159338 2.920087 3.136996 5.066089    10


microbenchmark(b <- selection_sort(u),times = 10)
expr      min       lq    mean   median       uq      max neval
21.50502 21.61436 31.7791 22.71371 40.64712 68.17705    10
```

Is this difference in speed ok? 
I know, maybe my codes are not efficient. If such difference is not ok, how can I correct it?

P.S both codes work correct

Selection sort

1. Given a vector x, let the initial unsorted vector u be equal to x, and
   the initial sorted vector s be a vector of length 0.
2. Find the smallest element of u then remove it from u and add it to
   the end of s.
3. If u is not empty then go back to step 2.

Insertion sort

1. Given a vector x, let the initial unsorted vector u be equal to x, and
   the initial sorted vector s be a vector of length 0.
2. Remove the last element of u and insert it into s so that s is still
   sorted.
3. If u is not empty then go back to step 2.

Comment: Insertion sort can run in `O(N)` in the best case but `O(N^2)` in the average case, whereas selection sort will run at `O(N^2)` in the best _and_ average case.

Comment: Read my comment there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37940405/rcpp-rbind-in-rcpp#comment63333305_37940405 Also, don't misuse `ifelse`.

Comment: @Roland I understood your idea. Do you mean the first code or both?

Comment: You are re-sizing vectors in both. Avoid that. E.g., you know how large `s` needs to be in the end. `vector` lets you specify the length.

Comment: @Roland Maybe I also should add the tasks, that I am solving.
Check it one more time please.

Comment: If you were given this task in the way stated, find yourself a different teacher. Growing an object is one of the slowest operations you can do (in any programming language, it's slow at the OS level).

Comment: @Roland  Thanks for your comments:)
Can you give a hint how to solve these problems(I mean insertion and selection sorts) without growing an object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an (relatively) efficient way to implement selection sort in R:

```
selection_sort <- function(x){
  s <- numeric(length(x))
  for (i in seq_len(length(x))) {
    ind <- which.min(x)
    s[i] <- x[ind]
    x[ind] <- NA
  }
  s
}

set.seed(42)
v <- rnorm(10)
selection_sort(v)
#[1] -0.56469817 -0.10612452 -0.09465904 -0.06271410  0.36312841  0.40426832  0.63286260  1.37095845  1.51152200  2.01842371
```

Note how I avoid resizing a vector and how I use a `for` loop, thereby avoiding the test in a `while` or `repeat` loop.

Comment: But I'm not sure if you are allowed to use `which.min`. And of course, if you didn't have the efficiency problem with resizing, removing elements would make finding the minimum faster.

Answer (score 1):

Similar idea (by @Roland) could also be implemented in [JuliaLang](http://julialang.org/) (including this option here as iteration is often fast in JuliaLang)

```
srand(42)
v =  randn(10)
v1 = deepcopy(v)
function sel_sort(x)
   s = zeros(length(x))
   for i in eachindex(x)
      ind = indmin(x)
      s[i] = x[ind]
      x[ind] = maximum(x) + 1
    end
  s
end


sel_sort(v)
#10-element Array{Float64,1}:
#-2.64199
#-1.1449
#-0.556027
#-0.468606
#-0.444383
#-0.299484
# 0.0271553
# 0.156143
# 1.00331
# 1.77786
```

---

In addition, we can also use the sorting algorithms already implemented

```
sort(v1, alg = InsertionSort)
# 10-element Array{Float64,1}:
#-2.64199
#-1.1449
#-0.556027
#-0.468606
#-0.444383
#-0.299484
#0.0271553
#0.156143
#1.00331
#1.77786
```

The `sort!` changes the original vector.

```
sort!(v1, alg = InsertionSort)
```